# Why this limit of integration?

Tags: calculus

I've been solving problems from the book by DeGroot and Schervish and I can't understand why *m* is the upper limit of integration in the solution to this problem. Why not the lower one?

Here is the problem:

Suppose that a random variable X has a continuous distribution for which the p.d.f. f is as follows:

$f(x) = 2x$ for $ 0< x <1, 0 $ otherwise

Determine the value of $d$ that minimizes $E(|X − d|)$.

Here is the solution:

$$ \int_0^m 2x \, dx=0.5  $$

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The answer from nbubis doesn't explain the last integral you gave.  I've posted an answer that does.  Setting that integral to $0.5$ is not "the solution", but it leads you quickly to the solution.

Comment: I find much confusion in the question and the answers.

Comment: ...and now there's somewhat less confusion.

Comment: ahaha;) cool! mathematics doesnt like confusion although it has this inside of his blood..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected value is given by (assuming $d$ is in $[0,1]$):
$$E = \int_0^1{2x|x-d|}dx = \int_0^d{2x(d-x)}dx + \int_d^1{2x(x-d)}dx$$
$$ = -\frac{2}{3} + d - \frac{2d^3}{3}$$
Derive by $d$ and compare to zero:
$$E' = 1 - 2d^2 = 0 \rightarrow d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation, nbubis!

Comment: I got $2d^2-1$, and so should you.

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes you are right. WHILE I posted my answer I did it based on nbubis's answer. I didnt check it by myself. I only focused on the second part of the question which say minimum! although it seemed to be maximum based on his answer. But you are completely right.

Answer (score 3):

The value of $d$ that that minimizes $E(|X-d|)$ is the median value of $X$, i.e. the value $m$ such that
$$
\Pr(X\le m) = 0.5 = \Pr(X\ge m).
$$

Thus for continuous distirbutions it is the value of $m$ for which
$$
\int_{-\infty}^m f_X(x)\,dx = 0.5 = \int_m^\infty f_X(x)\,dx.
$$

In your case, you want
$$
\int_0^m 2x\,dx = 0.5 = \int_m^1 2x\,dx.
$$
So $m^2 -0^2 = 0.5 = 1^2-m^2$.  Consequently $m= \sqrt{0.5}= \sqrt{2}/2$.

Answer (score 1):

I will note one important thing about the question. You will get $$E^{'}[X]=1-2d^2$$ as @nbubis wrote down already. When you find $$E^{''}[X]=-4d$$ and since $d\in[0,1]$ you have $$E^{''}[X]<0$$ which indicates that you have a *maximum* instead of *minimum* as you stated in the question
EDIT: Result was based on $$E^{'}[X]=1-2d^2$$ Since it is $$E^{'}[X]=2d^2-1,$$ there is a minimum. I didnt solve the first derivative by myself just copied.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification!

Comment: @Alan my pleasure;)

Comment: This is nonsense.  You get a minimum, not a maximum.  The derivative should be $2d^2-1$, not $1-2d^2$.